# How can I pass gulp.watch() to a pipe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a simple default tasking for linting changed js files:

```
    gulp.task('default', function() {
        // watch for JS changes
        gulp.watch(base + 'javascripts/**/*.js', function() {
            gulp.run('jshint');
        });
    });
```

The problem is that the `jshint` task again sources the files:

```
    gulp.task('jshint', function() {
        gulp.src([base + 'javascripts/*.js'])
            .pipe(jshint())
            .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
    });
```

What happens is that *all* files are linted, not only the changed ones.

Is there a way to pass only the changed files to jshint?

Comment: Mhm. Feels awkward as changed() needs a destination which I don't need since nothing is being changed. Seems sort of against the hype around gulp's ease of use?

Comment: Don't use `gulp.watch` for incremental work, [use the `gulp-watch` plugin, instead.](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-watch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to @OverZealous I've found this approach to work using `gulp-watch`:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src(base + 'javascripts/**/*.js', { read: false })
        .pipe(watch())
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});
```

The `{ read: false }` is required to avoid linting all files on startup.
This solution does *not* lint files that didn't exist when first being started.